# Magento 1.9 Invoice PDF Print Issue on Arabic text appear in crossed boxes

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos, pdf-generation, magento-1.9

**Description of issue**

I am facing an issue with printing invoices, shipments and packing slip when a customer inputs billing/shipping information in Arabic. The downloaded PDF will look like the below screenshot, without decoding (Compiling) Arabic characters.

[Pdf invoice shows crossed box on Arabic characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hq6M.png)

Expected Result: Invoices, Shipments, and Packingslips should display all information properly, whether in English and/or Arabic. Without using third-party extensions.

**System information**

- CentOS 7
- Magento 1.9.2.4

**Tried solutions**

I have exhausted the internet references, nothing really worked, the best I managed to do is the following.

1- Font forcing

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/AraJozoor-Regular.ttf');
```

The PDF document came out with separated characters, similar to the attached image.

[Arabic text with separated and reversed characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiDHs.png)

When I tried to print invoice pdf with Arabic words it's giving separate characters instead of the complete Arabic word. The single characters of Arabic script are not shown from right to left, but from left to right and it splits as single chars.E.g.: مدرسة (school) is shown like ة س ر د م

Unlike other Right-to-Left languages, such as Hebrew, which has the same issue, and which can be solved by just reversing characters. In Arabic, the characters must be connected to each other.

I have partially solved character reverse issue while maintaining other English words using the following piece of code. but it is still, prints each character separately.

```
    function fixText($text){ 
      if(preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $text ) ){
       preg_match_all('/./us', $text, $ar);
       $text = join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
       $words = explode( ' ', $text );
foreach( $words as $i => $word ){
    if( !preg_match( "/\p{Arabic}/u", $word ) ){
        $words[$i] = implode( '', array_reverse( str_split( $word ) ) );
    }
}
$text = implode( ' ', $words );
 return $text; }}
```

2- Font-family server update

If you try to send the invoice via email, there is no Arabic text issue, even though it is generated by the same function. So my attention heads towerds the server trying to update fonts. and I used the following codes to do so.

```
yum install linux-libertine-fonts
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Which is the font package used by Magento

3- Using TCPDF library instead of Zend pdf library

Answer (score 0):

This can be helf you

1) Please Download the font that support  Arabic text and symbol.

2) Place the font in lib directory

3) Please override this file  app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php and app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php
and replace

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');
```

with

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

I used it on magento 1.9
Please don't use this font "dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf"
You should your language and symbol supported font

Comment: Thank you Balasaheb, I have tried your suggested font package, I get the same result in the first tried solution (separated Arabic characters)

Comment: Hello Ahmad can you test with Arabic language words and symbol supported font

Comment: I did that with AraJozoor-Regular and Cairo fonts, the same, characters are separated  E.g.: مدرسة (school) is shown like ة س ر د م

Comment: @AhmadMubiden I have same issues, if you have fixed the issues please let me know the solutions